# Add custom button for files loading

Tags: reactjs, filepond

I'm using filepond with react and material-ui.

If I add very basic filepond component, like this:

```
 <FilePond name="files" labelIdle="" />
```

It will render default browser input with type `file`, like this:

[image]

I want to render custom material-ui button instead. I know that FilePond can be styled in a different way via CSS, but it's not about styling with CSS-classes, but about inserting predefined component, like naterial-ui one. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code in the github, linked here, https://github.com/pqina/react-filepond/blob/master/lib/index.js, the package is creating the input element directly rather than wrapping a passed in component. Therefore you cannot pass in a predefined Material-UI component. If you want to use Material-UI styles you'll have to do the styling yourself or edit the filepond package to support passing in a component.